# Which OS, SQL, Postfix and Dovecot files/folder need to be backup for disaster recovery?

Tags: rsync, mysql, postfix, dovecot

I'm running an e-mail server (Postfix/Dovecot) on a Pi4, Buster OS. We want to setup a parallel Pi (same basic image) and use `rsync` to transfer critical files to this Pi using a `cron` job on a regular schedule (daily, hourly, ...).

I know that the mail content files (`/var/vmail`) and the SQL files (`/var/lib/mysql`) are important, but are there other critical e-mail server files which need to be transferred?

The goal here is to have a "backup" server up-to-date, ready and configured if the primary server has a serious failure.

Comment: You're highly unlikely to be able to `rsync` the MySQL database files in `/var/lib/mysql` safely, unless you're copying from a filesystem snapshot

Answer (score 1):

The config (`/etc/postfix`, `/etc/dovecot`, `/etc/mysql`), potentially the users (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group`), and the spool directories (`/var/spool/mail`, `/var/spool/postfix`) are obvious candidates.

Remember: a backup is not a backup until you've tested restoring it.